# LaTeX page-breaking with multiple tabular environments

Tags: tables, page-breaking

In the following example LaTeX (pdflatex and lualatex) does start on the first page with the typesetting but on the second, also the page is not broken correctly after August.

I would have expected this to happen with float objects but not with ordinary tables.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm, top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} \multicolumn{7}{c}{April 2020} \\ \toprule
Mo & Di & Mi & Do & Fr & Sa & So \\ \midrule
  &  &1 &2 &3 &4 &5\\
6 &7 &8 &9 &10 &11 &12\\
13 &14 &15 &16 &17 &18 &19\\
20 &21 &22 &23 &24 &25 &26\\
27 &28 &29 &30 &  &  & \\
\bottomrule \end{tabular}  \vspace*{2.5em}


\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} \multicolumn{7}{c}{Mai 2020} \\ \toprule
Mo & Di & Mi & Do & Fr & Sa & So \\ \midrule
  &  &  &  &1 &2 &3\\
4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10\\
11 &12 &13 &14 &15 &16 &17\\
18 &19 &20 &21 &22 &23 &24\\
25 &26 &27 &28 &29 &30 &31\\
\bottomrule \end{tabular}  \vspace*{2.5em}


\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} \multicolumn{7}{c}{Juni 2020} \\ \toprule
Mo & Di & Mi & Do & Fr & Sa & So \\ \midrule
1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7\\
8 &9 &10 &11 &12 &13 &14\\
15 &16 &17 &18 &19 &20 &21\\
22 &23 &24 &25 &26 &27 &28\\
29 &30 &  &  &  &  & \\
\bottomrule \end{tabular}  \vspace*{2.5em}


\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} \multicolumn{7}{c}{Juli 2020} \\ \toprule
Mo & Di & Mi & Do & Fr & Sa & So \\ \midrule
  &  &1 &2 &3 &4 &5\\
6 &7 &8 &9 &10 &11 &12\\
13 &14 &15 &16 &17 &18 &19\\
20 &21 &22 &23 &24 &25 &26\\
27 &28 &29 &30 &31 &  & \\
\bottomrule \end{tabular}  \vspace*{2.5em}


\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} \multicolumn{7}{c}{August 2020} \\ \toprule
Mo & Di & Mi & Do & Fr & Sa & So \\ \midrule
  &  &  &  &  &1 &2\\
3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9\\
10 &11 &12 &13 &14 &15 &16\\
17 &18 &19 &20 &21 &22 &23\\
24 &25 &26 &27 &28 &29 &30\\
31 &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\bottomrule \end{tabular}  \vspace*{2.5em}



\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} \multicolumn{7}{c}{September 2020} \\ \toprule
Mo & Di & Mi & Do & Fr & Sa & So \\ \midrule
  &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6\\
7 &8 &9 &10 &11 &12 &13\\
14 &15 &16 &17 &18 &19 &20\\
21 &22 &23 &24 &25 &26 &27\\
28 &29 &30 &  &  &  & \\
\bottomrule \end{tabular}  \vspace*{2.5em}

\end{document}
```

[image: first page empty]

[image: second page]

Comment: I gave your code a try and after reformating it (to help with eventual longer debugging visually) i had the suspicion that its the * after vspace so i removed them and it works typesetting starts at page 1 (which is no longer empty) and after august there is a page break and september is at page 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment above removing the `*` after the `vspace` did the trick on my machine you find the code below for reference:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm, top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} 
        \multicolumn{7}{c}{April 2020}\\
        \toprule
          Mo & Di & Mi & Do & Fr & Sa & So\\
        \midrule
             &    & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5 \\
          6  & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12\\
          13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19\\
          20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26\\
          27 & 28 & 29 & 30 &    &    &   \\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{2.5em}

    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} 
        \multicolumn{7}{c}{Mai 2020}\\
        \toprule
        Mo & Di & Mi & Do & Fr & Sa & So\\
        \midrule
           &    &    &    & 1  &  2 &  3 \\
         4 & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  &  9 & 10 \\
        11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\
        18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
        25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 \\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{2.5em}

    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} 
        \multicolumn{7}{c}{Juni 2020}\\
        \toprule
        Mo & Di & Mi & Do & Fr & Sa & So\\
        \midrule
         1 & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7 \\
         8 & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14\\
        15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21\\
        22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28\\
        29 & 30 &    &    &    &    &   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{2.5em}

    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} 
        \multicolumn{7}{c}{Juli 2020}\\
        \toprule
        Mo & Di & Mi & Do & Fr & Sa & So\\
        \midrule
           &    & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5  \\
         6 & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 \\
        20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
        27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 &    &    \\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{2.5em}

    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
        \multicolumn{7}{c}{August 2020}\\
        \toprule
        Mo & Di & Mi & Do & Fr & Sa & So\\
        \midrule
           &    &    &    &    & 1  &  2\\
         3 & 4  &  5 &  6 & 7  & 8  &  9\\
        10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\
        17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23\\
        24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30\\
        31 &    &    &    &    &    &   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{2.5em}

    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
        \multicolumn{7}{c}{September 2020}\\
        \toprule
        Mo & Di & Mi & Do & Fr & Sa & So\\
        \midrule
           & 1  &  2 &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6\\
         7 & 8  &  9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13\\
        14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20\\
        21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27\\
        28 & 29 & 30 &    &    &    &   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
    \vspace{2.5em}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the result]

Comment: it's also good practice to put the blank line before the vspace, not after.